# How can I see the Write-Host output of a script resource in Powershell DSC?

Tags: powershell, dsc

How can I see the `Write-Host` or `Write-Verbose` of an external script running in the [script resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/scriptresource) when using Powershell DSC?

In the example below, I would like to see the output of the `C:\ProgramData\Script.ps1`:

```
Configuration ConfigurationWithExternalScript
{
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration

    Script ExecuteExternalScript {
        TestScript = { return $False },
        GetScript = { @{Result = $env:STATE_VARIABLE } },
        SetScript = { C:\ProgramData\Script.ps1 -verbose }
    }
}
```

I have tried:

- `Start-DscConfiguration .\Path\To\Configuration\ -wait -verbose -force` but this does not give any output for the script itself.
- looking in the `Microsoft-Windows-Dsc/Operational` logs on the configured machine
- looking in the `C:\Windows\System32\Configuration\ConfigurationStatus\` logs on the configured machine
- [enabling `Microsoft-Windows-Dsc/Analytic` and `Microsoft-Windows-Dsc/Debug`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2014/01/03/using-event-logs-to-diagnose-errors-in-desired-state-configuration/) on the configured machine (there's no output to these logs)

Comment: The write verbose wil be written in the console. Start PowerShell ISE and run the command Start-DscConfiguration .\Path\To\Configuration\ -wait -verbose -force. Then you should see the write-verbose output

Comment: I'm looking for the verbose output of the script running in the script resource rather than the output of the script resource. I've updated my question to reflect this meaning.

Comment: I don't get it. What script in the script resource?

Comment: I've added an example to my question.

Comment: Rewrite your Script which you want to exectue to a DSC Resource?

Comment: I've noticed that: if the script exits successfully, it writes the script output verbosely; if it doesn't exit successfully, it does not write any output verbosely.

Answer (score 1):

Since your script (Script.ps1) is running in a different process you're not going to necessarily see the output in the console that you're running the config from - especially if there's an error. My suggestion would be to redirect the output from your Script.ps1 file to a log file rather than using verbose. That way you'll be able to see all of the messages from the file whether or not the script fails.